# how can use golang c-shared library in go with .h and .so file?

Tags: c, linux, go, cgo

I had try call so file by define c code in same go file, It works!
but when I want use .h and .so file to do it. It not work.
this is my code:

### sdk.go

```
package main

//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
import "C"

func main() {

}

//export query
func query(info *C.char) *C.char {
    GoStr := C.GoString(info)
    return C.CString(GoStr)
}
```

i generate the so file with command:

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o sdk.so sdk.go
```

now I want to call it:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L../lib -lsdk
#include "sdk.h"
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    val := C.query(C.CString("123"))
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

but some err occured,

```
Starting: /home/go/bin/dlv dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:45412 --log-dest=3 from /root/goProject/src/cgo/src
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:45412
Build Error: go build -o /root/goProject/src/cgo/src/__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l .
# CGO/src
./main.go:11:9: could not determine kind of name for C.query
cgo: 
gcc errors for preamble:
In file included from ./main.go:5:0:
cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog:49:17: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'query' (exit status 2)
```

I think this may because the sdk.h format.
it looks like https://go.dev/play/p/rxlUp16s-u9

any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated...

### last

i think the problem is can't receive go string from so file, so i change the data type from go source file, string to *C.char, and everything is ok now.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your *question*. If you have a solution, post an answer instead.

Comment: You cannot use a cgo shared library in a go program.

Comment: @JimB, Em... why not, I want to say I can do this and do it work now, just according cgo document.

Comment: Because you have 2 go runtimes in the same process which can interfere, leading to crashes or other unexpected behavior.